# Loop a renaming script, convert 3 files using ImageMagick into a montage, and then sending the file to another folder

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm currently using Raspberry Pi 3B, and would like to create a bash script that will continually run in the background waiting for:

In a folder named PHOTOS, containing sequential .jpg with the names photobooth_shot_00001.jpg, photobooth_shot_00002.jpg, photobooth_shot_00003.jpg, etc..

I would like to rename the every 3 newly generated .jpg with the names "GROUP-1-1.jpg," "GROUP-1-2.jpg," "GROUP-1-3.jpg", WITH GROUP-*-[1-3].jpg increasing sequentially.

Then, converting every 3 pictures from each "GROUP-*" into a montage with the following bash script using ImageMagick:

```
    convert \
\( -size 600x400 xc:white \) \
\( GROUP-*-1.jpg -resize 370x \) -geometry +19+29 -compose over -composite \
\( GROUP-*-2.jpg -resize 187x \) -geometry +398+29 -compose over -composite \
\( GROUP-*-3.jpg -resize 187x \) -geometry +398+175 -compose over -composite \
\( watermark.png \) -geometry +0-10  -compose over -composite \
-density 100 GROUP-*-RESULT.jpg
```

Finally, sending the "GROUP-*-RESULT.jpg" to another folder called "PRINT"

It's been really tough just trying to re-name them...Thank you for any help!

Comment: One of the  consideration points is how to manage the jpeg files which have been already processed.
Is it acceptable to remove them from PHOTOS directory, or to move to another directory e.g. subfolder in PHOTOS?

Comment: Yes, I agree the original photobooth_shot_*.jpg should be moved to another subfolder..

Comment: Please try to focus your question on one thing. Is it about how to wait for photos to be created? Or is it about how to rename photos? Or is it about montaging photos together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your missing part is how you can rename the image files, please try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

photodir="PHOTOS"           # dir to store originally generated images
donedir="$photodir/done"    # dir to backup processed files
seqfile="$photodir/seq"     # file to keep the sequential group number

# read file names in $photodir, sort in increasing order and store in an array
while read -r -d "" f; do
    ary+=("$f")
done < <(find "$photodir" -type f -name "photobooth_shot_*.jpg" -print0 | sort -z)

# abort if #files is less than three
if (( ${#ary[@]} < 3 )); then
    echo "hoge"
    exit
fi

# read last group number if the file exists
if [[ -f $seqfile ]]; then
    seq=$(<"$seqfile")
else
    seq=0
fi
seq=$((++seq))

mkdir -p "$donedir"

# rename top three files
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    newname=$(printf "%s/GROUP-%d-%d.jpg" "$photodir" "$seq" "$((++i))")
    newary+=("$newname")
    mv -- "${ary[$i]}" "$newname"
done

# perform ImageMagick "convert" here
#   for the files "GROUP-${seq}-[1-3].jpg" or "${newary[@]}"

# backup processed files
mv -- "${newary[@]}" "$donedir"

# store the group number for next invocation
echo "$seq" > "$seqfile"
```

- Please put your ImageMagick command in around the "perform ImageMagick" line.
- The script is supposed to be invoked periodically (e.g. every 1 minute or so,
  depending on the frequency of new image generation).
- The script should not be executed simultaneously (in parallel).

Hope this helps.

**[EDIT]**

The script below is an updated version according your requirements:

```
#!/bin/bash

photodir="PHOTOS"           # dir to store originally generated images
donedir="$photodir/done"    # dir to backup processed files
seqfile="$photodir/seq"     # file to keep the sequential group number

# wait for the growing file to be completed by watching the filesize
# it may not be 100% reliable depending on the file creation process

waitfile() {
    file=$1

    if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then
        return
    fi
    while true; do
        size0=$(stat -c %s "$file")
        sleep 1
        size1=$(stat -c %s "$file")
        sleep 1
        size2=$(stat -c %s "$file")
        if (( $size0 == $size1 && $size1 == $size2 )); then
            return
        fi
    done
}

# exit immediately if the same name process still exists
#  (the previous execution is still working..)
scriptname=${0##*/}
count=$(ps -aux | grep "$scriptname" | wc -l)
if (( $count > 3 )); then
    exit
fi

# read file names in $photodir, sort in increasing order and store in an array
while read -r -d "" f; do
    ary+=("$f")
done < <(find "$photodir" -type f -name "photobooth_shot_*.jpg" -print0 | sort -z)

# abort if #files is less than three
if (( ${#ary[@]} < 3 )); then
#   echo "hoge"             # this line is for debugging purpose
    exit
fi

# find auto-composite photos
while read -r -d "" f; do
    ary2+=("$f")
done < <(find "$photodir" -type f -name "photobooth[0-9]*.jpg" -print0 | sort -z
)

# abort if no auto-composite photos are found
if (( ${#ary2[@]} < 1)); then
#   echo "hoge"         # this is for debugging purpose
    exit
fi

composite="${ary2[0]}"
waitfile "$composite"       # wait for the auto-composite file to be complete

# read last group number if the file exists
if [[ -f $seqfile ]]; then
    seq=$(<"$seqfile")
else
    seq=0
fi
seq=$((++seq))

mkdir -p "$donedir"

# rename top three files
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    newname=$(printf "%s/GROUP-%d-%d.jpg" "$photodir" "$seq" "$((++i))")
    newary+=("$newname")
    mv -- "${ary[$i]}" "$newname"
done

# rename the auto-composite file
newname2=$(printf "%s/GROUP-%d-ORIGINAL.jpg" "$photodir" "$seq")
mv -- "$composite" "$newname2"

# perform ImageMagick "convert" here
#   for the files "GROUP-${seq}-[1-3].jpg" or "${newary[@]}"

# move the auto-composite file to the designated folder
# mv -- "$newname2" "destdir"

# backup processed files
mv -- "${newary[@]}" "$donedir"

# store the group number for next invocation
echo "$seq" > "$seqfile"
```

Comment: hi again, was wondering if you could help me with another re-naming script...this may not be the right medium, but was hoping to get your expertise! it's a python script that monitors for any files that is dropped into a folder called PRINT, and it sends the file to printer via CUPS, and then sends the file back to another folder called READY. The script works, but I would like to re-name every file that is printed with GROUP-1-MONTAGE(1).jpg (for first printed), GROUP-1-MONTAGE(2).jpg (for 2nd printed), etc..is there any way to private message you? thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the message, but I'd recommend to ask the question in an appropriate way (e.g. python tagged thread in SO), not directly to me. BTW your requirements look very similar to the previous one except for the difference using CUPS. I suppose you have already known how to solve it by yourself with a little effort. Good luck.